# Pokémon Bank Error Code 006-0105 help?

Tags: pokemon-bank

Today I downloaded and paid for the PokéBank (or Pokémon Bank). Brigette came up, and she said she was going to "get Pokémon Bank all ready for you to use." It showed the loading Pokéball for a good minute, before coming up with... [image: Error Code 006-0105]

I've tried closing the app and re-opening it multiple times, changing the game card between X, White 2 and even no game at all, and it comes up with the same popup. Is there something wrong with my app, or am I just impatient, and the console, or even Nintendo itself, need 24 hours (or something like that) to verify that I've bought it?

Comment: There's no waiting period required - maybe the server just had a brief outage? How many times have you tried (and how far apart)?

Comment: @Tystnad What I always do when I see this is go to Nintendo's Help Page and look up the error code.  99% of the time I get an answer why my application isn't working or is having trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Nintendo's [Help Page](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/wfc/en_na/ds/results.jsp?error_code=006-0105&system=3DS&locale=en_US):

> ## **Error Code: 006-0105**
>
> **Situation:**
>
> You were disconnected while using an online feature, such as Pokémon
>   Bank.
>
> **What to Do:**
>
> - If you receive this error code, move closer to your wireless router or access point and try again.
> - If the issue persists, review your DNS settings, and update the settings to auto-obtain. [[How to]](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/217/p/430)
>
>   - If this is already set to auto-obtain, you may try entering an alternate DNS, such as Google's DNS. [[How to]](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/217/p/430)
>
> **Situation Not Resolved:**
>
> If the issue continues for an extended amount of time, please contact
>   Nintendo by calling 1-800-255-3700. Representatives are available from
>   6 a.m. to 7 p.m., Pacific Time, 7 days a week.

In short, you were disconnected when you were running Pokemon Bank (went out of your router's WI-FI range, router disconnected, etc.), and reconnecting and staying connected should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this, and it still doesn't work. I'll try turning my Internet off and on again to see if that's the problem, but worse comes to worse I'll probably have to call Nintendo.